# Random Integer Sequences

Tags: matrix, random, algorithm

I want to construct a random square matrix in the following manner:

[image]

a) Three states `[0 | 1 | 2]` are repeated `[2 | 4 | 6 | 8 | 10]` times in each row

b) All numbers of current row must be different from the numbers directly above them

I have written:

Make one row

```
mrow := Module[{x},
  Take[
   Flatten @ Table[x = RandomInteger[{0, 2}];
     Table[x, {RandomChoice[{2, 4, 6, 8}]}], {5}],
   10]]
```

Prepare matrix with indexed variable `row`. Determine by subtraction whether next row is different. If not `While` - loop until a different row is found.

```
For[n = 2; row[1] = mrow, n <= 10, n++,
 row[n] = mrow;
 While[MemberQ[row[n - 1] - row[n], 0], row[n] = mrow]];
```

Output matrix

```
Map[row[#] &, Range[10]] // MatrixPlot
```

[image]

Unfortunately, for the first time, I had to use `For` and `While` with MMA programming.

Do you see any functional way to get the desired result?

Comment: BTW, there are `5 3^5 2^20` possible configurations. Not all of them are equally probable, though

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Here's an approach without `If` or `For`. First a helper function:

```
(* Thanks to Belisarius for the mrow& suggestion *)
 g[x_] := NestWhile[mrow&, x, MemberQ[x - #, 0] &]
```

Then:

```
NestList[g, mrow, 9] // MatrixPlot
```

Where `mrow` is as you've defined it in the question.

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: +1. You don't need `f[]` ... `g[x_] := NestWhile[mrow &, x, MemberQ[x - #, 0] &]`

Comment: @Belisarius, Thanks, I knew my brain was failing me :). I'll update.

Comment: BTW I find this solution _really_ nice

Comment: @Belisarius. Thanks. I almost gave up on it.

Comment: First time that I see a non-pure function (`mrow`) ending with a `&`. Some day I'll understand. Let me upvote in-between :)

Comment: @eldo. It's actually a very useful trick e.g `Array[5&, 10]` is equivalent to `ConstantArray[5, 10]`

Answer (score 4):

Nice question. I'd try to do something with recursion instead, like

```
Clear[f];

f[n_] := f[n] = newRow[f[n - 1]]
f[0] = ConstantArray[10, 10];

newRow[previousRow_] := With[{row = mrow},
  If[MemberQ[previousRow - row, 0], newRow[previousRow], row]
  ]
Array[f, 10] // MatrixPlot
```

Comment: Your elegant solution functions perfectly. Many thanks :)

Answer (score 2):

```
 row := Take[
         NestWhile[Join[#, ConstantArray[RandomInteger[{0, 2}],
             RandomChoice[{2, 4, 6, 8}]]]  &, {} , Length@# < 10 &], 10]

 Nest[Module[{b}, (While[Times @@ (#[[-1]] - (b = row)) == 0];
       Append[#, b])] & , {row} , 9] // MatrixPlot
```